# UIView Animation Block Makes No Changes

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

The following code is sheer simple. `_facebookF` is a `UIImageView`.

```
if (animationOn == YES) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        [_faceBookF setAlpha:0];
    }];
    [_faceBookF setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebookFBlue.png"]];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        [_faceBookF setAlpha:1];
    }];

     } else {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        [_faceBookF setAlpha:0];
    }];
    [_faceBookF setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebookF.png"]];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
         [_faceBookF setAlpha:1];
    }];
}
```

The app gets to the method which contains this code fine, but no changes to the UI occur throughout the entire block of code. To my knowledge, the app is running on the main thread.

Any guesses?

**UPDATE**--In fact, the issue is that the image is not being changed at all--with or without the animation. Both images are accessed fine in other parts of the app.

Comment: Probably the same person who downvoted with no comment as well.

Comment: Can you confirm that the image view is not nil at this point in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses. I've implemented the completion block you both mentioned to avoid both animations firing at once. However, the main issue had to do with the method not being accessed properly. I can't see exactly why, as the `facebookF` variable was not nil, and the if and log statements in the method worked fine. Anyway, I have switched to a `NSNotification` solution, and now all parts of the method are being accessed.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to run sequential animations, but the way you have coded them, they are likely to run in parallel.  What you need to do is this:

```
if (animationOn == YES) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        [_faceBookF setAlpha:0];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [_faceBookF setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebookFBlue.png"]];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
           [_faceBookF setAlpha:1];
        }];
    }];



 } 
 else {
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
      [_faceBookF setAlpha:0];
   }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [_faceBookF setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebookF.png"]];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
         [_faceBookF setAlpha:1];
    }];
 }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I actually just found that the root of the issue is that the image is not being changed. The image to change to/from is within the project hierarchy and is linked to the target. Why could this be?

Comment: Perhaps the target in Interface Builder is not what you expect.  Be sure that the nib is linked to the correct UIViewController

Comment: Well, I'm using a storyboard, and it looks fine. Also, the same images I'm having trouble with are accessed fine elsewhere in the app, which makes me think it's a memory issue.

Comment: Like @borrrden said above, be sure that the UIImageView (_faceBookF) is not nil when you are trying to set it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. This starts the second animation after the first has completed. So it will fade out the UIImageView and then fade it up with different version of the image.

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.4
                  animations:^
     {
         [_faceBookF setAlpha:0];
     }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         [_faceBookF setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebookFBlue.png"]];
         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                          animations:^
          {
              [_faceBookF setAlpha:1];
          }];
     }];
```